# Run script with android app

Tags: android, bash, shell, button

i've got this shell script:

```
#!system/bin/sh
while :
do
sync
echo 3> /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
echo "Script is been launched"
sleep 30m
done
exit 0;
```

i wish run this script with an android app. I have already created a button with only a toast for now. How can i take the script (free.sh) and launch it with the button on the app? Or is there a solution to rewrite the code in java? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will use Eclipse to create a simple Android Hello World app. And add a button in your layout. This is a very preliminary practice of Android development which you can dig a lot more from http://d.android.com

Please try this code in your button's `OnClick` call back function:

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.buttonPower);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Process p=null;
            try {
               p = new ProcessBuilder()
                    .command("PathToYourScript")
                    .start();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             } finally {
                if(p!=null) p.destroy();
             }
        }
 });
```

Comment: Now i'm at work so when i go home i try. So in PATH_TO_YOUR_SH_SCRIPT i'll put for example sdcard/free.sh but in VAR_FOR_YOUR_SCRIPT? Is there also a way to stop the shell with another button? Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: I am afraid that you cannot put your shell script on SDCARD since the file system won't let you give any X permission to a file. You'd better put the file in your own cache diretory, by default in /data/data/com.yourpackage.name/files. And if your script dose not take any parameters, just pass empty string: ""

Comment: mmh, well now the shell is on sdcard and if i try to run it with the terminal emulator goes. However if doesn't work i'll change the path.. But i still don't understand what put on VAR_FOR_YOUR_SCRIPT line. What you mean with VAR_FOR_YOUR_SCRIPT?

Comment: Please, just refer to the Android developer site for the reference of java.lang.process usage.

Comment: Ok i'll looking at these but the only one thing i ask you is what is VAR_FOR_YOUR_SCRIPT?.

Comment: The default sample is .command("/system/bin/ping", "www.google.com"), so if you do not have any parameter for the programme you are going to invoke, just left it empty.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can run a shell script from your android app

```
try {
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /sdcard/test.sh");
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
       String listOfFiles = "";
       String line;
       while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                listOfFiles += line;
       }
 }
 catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got errors in my code:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.toast.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Process process = new ProcessBuilder()
                .command("PATH")
                .redirectErrorStream(true)
                .start();
                try {
                    InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
                    readStream(in);// Here: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete `Block`

                finally {
                    process.destroy();
                }
            }
        }
        }); //Here: Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
    }

    protected void readStream(InputStream in) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes my sample code is same as the one from Android developer site, it is easy for you to fix it manually. And I mean, do you have any other errors?

Comment: Not yet xD. But really i can't resolve this one. And i don't know how to see if the script actually goes.

Comment: Always same errors...can you help me getting my code and fix it please? really i can't fix it

Comment: That code i posted.. It's 2 days i can't found the errors. I can't fix it.. Remember i'm a noob developer with android so it's normal i can't see and fix some errors.

Comment: If you want my email is davide.dellai@hotmail.it

Answer (score 0):

Well, now No errors (THANK YOU!) but do nothing..to try I've written an easy script that writes a file.txt. See the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

         button = findViewById(R.id.button1);
         button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
              @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Process p=null;
                    try {
                         p = new ProcessBuilder()
                              .command("/sdcard/Script/scritturafile.sh")
                              .start();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                     } finally {
                         if(p!=null) p.destroy();
                     }
               }
          });
     }
}
```

The are no errors but when I press the button I think the shell doesn't go so don't create the file.txt

Comment: This is part of the log: W/System.err(15320): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/sdcard/Script/scritturafile.sh] Working Directory: null Environment.

Comment: 1. You should try to execute an /system/bin/sh first, and redirect the input/output, and write your script into its input stream. 2. Even you have declared your write external storage permission, it doesn't mean your child process does. So if you need special permission, try other way out.

Comment: I tryied another way..Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909530/drop-caches-by-app-doesnt-work . Now i can write bash code directly from java but not what i want xD. mkdir, writing a file txt or other yes but what i want (echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches) not. Can you take a look please? I think i'm almost arrived at my goal but i miss something! Really sorry, i promise you i will pay a beer ahaha :)